# Why is gnome-todo not installed although it's a dependency of ubuntu-desktop?

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04

Why is gnome-todo not installed when it is a dependency of ubuntu-desktop meta package in 18.04?

```
$ apt-cache rdepends  gnome-todo
gnome-todo
Reverse Depends:
  libecal-1.2-19
  vanilla-gnome-desktop
  gnome
  ubuntu-desktop
  libgnome-todo-dev
  libgnome-todo-dev
  libgnome-todo
  libgnome-todo
  gir1.2-gtd-1.0
  gnome-todo-common
  gnome-todo-common
  gir1.2-gtd-1.0
$ apt-cache policy gnome-todo
gnome-todo:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.28.1-1
  Version table:
     3.28.1-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
$ dpkg -l | grep ubuntu-desktop
ii  ubuntu-desktop                             1.417                                                    amd64        The Ubuntu desktop system
$ dpkg -l | grep todo
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.417).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Update: This situation probably results from an interrupted and subsequently repaired upgrade to 18.04.  Would doug's suggestion (sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop) restore all the default/recommended packages that are installed during an upgrade?

Comment: It's not installed on Ubuntu 16.04, and I can't find anything in the support version of Ubuntu that requires it.  If it's a requisite of the 18.04 operation, there is a good chance that it will be install when 18.04 is released.  If the developers are making a mistake, it's important that you file a bug report to get the issue addressed.   All the bugs may not be completely worked out before the release, but it would help if you would use the proper channel for support.  Please report and track your bug (including feature request) at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Comment: It's a recommend of `ubuntu-desktop`, if you were to remove & then re-install `ubuntu-desktop` it would likely get installed. Also `gnome-todo`is on the current 18.04 image so no bug.. Check the .manifest here http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Comment: Thanks. I see now that "apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop" lists gnome-todo as a recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gnome-todo` is a recommendation of `ubuntu-desktop`. As such it can be removed without removing the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package.
Also to note that it will be included on the 18.04 release image.

In this case it should suffice to remove & then reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` package

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```